# Cypher : Return Nodes that matched along with Nodes that didn't match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

With Labels A, B, and Z, A and B have their own relationships to Z.  With the query

```
MATCH (a:A)
MATCH (b:B { uuid: {id} })
MATCH (a)-[:rel1]->(z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b)
WITH a, COLLECT(z) AS matched_z
RETURN DISTINCT a, matched_z
```

Which returns the nodes of A and all the Nodes Z that have a relationship to A and B

I'm stuck on trying to ALSO return a separate array of the Z Nodes that B has with Z but not with A (i.e. missing_z).  I am attempting to do an initial query to return all the relationships between B & Z

```
results = MATCH (b:B { uuid: {id} })
MATCH (b)-[:rel2]->(z:Z)
RETURN DISTINCT COLLECT(z.uuid) AS z

MATCH (a:A)
MATCH (b:B { uuid: {id} })
MATCH (a)-[:rel1]->(z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b)
WITH a, COLLECT(z) AS matched_z, z
RETURN DISTINCT a, matched_z, filter(skill IN z.array WHERE NOT z.uuid IN {results}) AS missing_z
```

The results seem to have nil for missing_z where one would assume it should be populated.  Not sure if filter is the correct way to go with a WHERE NOT / IN scenario.  Can the above 2 queries be combined into 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part here, in my opinion, is that any failed matches will drop everything you have matched so far. But your starting point seems to be "All Z related by B.uuid", So start by collecting that and filtering/copying from there.

Use WITH + aggregation functions to copy+filter columns

Use OPTIONAL MATCH if a failure to match shouldn't drop already collected rows.

If I understand what you are trying to do well enough, This cypher should do the job, and just adjust it as needed (let me know if you need help understanding any part of it/adapting it)

```
// Match base set
MATCH (z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b:B { uuid: {id} })
// Collect into single list
WITH COLLECT(z) as zs
// Match all A (ignore relation to Zs) 
MATCH (a:A)
// For each a, return a, the sub-list of Zs related to a, and the sub-list of Zs not related to a
RETURN a as a, FILTER(n in zs WHERE (a)-[:rel1]->(n)) as matched, FILTER(n in zs WHERE NOT (a)-[:rel1]->(n)) as unmatched
```

Comment: On second glance, its not working how I expected....  I already have nodes of A that I need to qualify more on with above.  In the Filter() I added n in z.array because I was getting an expecting a Collection not Node error and (a) instead of (:A) i.e. ( n in z.array WHERE NOT (a)-[:rel1]->(z)) as unmatchedZ ). 
The matchedZ portion seems to be all the nodes in the relationship between B and Z, but matchedZ should reflect the Z nodes that are the same for A and B.  Which is why I was using MATCH (a)-[:rel1]->(z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b) to get those.  UnmatchedZ is also unpopulated.  Confused. :)

Comment: @ndyr One thing I would recommend while building up your initial Cyphers, is to work on them one command at a time. Start with a simple `MATCH(z:Z) RETURN *`, and with each iteration, add or remove one thing from the Cypher until you have collected the things you want. This is good for seeing what each part of the Cypher is actually matching/filtering. I fixed the initial filter, but I'm afraid I am too confused about what you need to actually help you further. If you add some sample data to your question, and what you want your query to return from that data, I can help you much better.

Comment: Sure!
Maybe there is some confusion, A and B labels have Z's associated to them, in my initial query I can find specific A's in a region, then with the resulting nodes find what Z nodes they have in common with
MATCH (a)-[:rel1]->(z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b). I successfully get these matching Z's, which I will set with z as matchingZ.  Next I'm trying to figure out how to do a filter on that matchingZ.  
The query (z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b) contain will contain all the nodes in matchingZ plus left over ones.  These left over ones are the ones I am trying to return also.

Comment: So the return will have the A nodes that fit the conditions, a collection of matching Z to b:B, and a collection of the unmatching Z to b:B

Comment: START l=node:a_location('withinDistance:[lat,lon, 50.0]')
MATCH (l)-[:a_location]->(a:A)
WHERE {where_clause}
MATCH (a)
MATCH (b:B { uuid: b_id})
MATCH (c:C { uuid: c_id })
WHERE {where clause do with above nodes}
MATCH (a)-[:rel1]->(z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b)
WITH a, z AS matchingZ
RETURN DISTINCT a as a_results, COLLECT(matchingZ) as matchingZ

This returns what I expect. Now, in the last WITH I am adding
WITH a, b, z as matchingZ, FILTER(n in s.array WHERE NOT (:Z)<-[:rel2]-(o)) as missingZ

When I get the RETURN I would expect the remaing z's in COLLET(missingZ), but not getting them.

Comment: @ndyr Edited Cypher. If this still isn't what you're trying to achieve, can you add example data (CREATE cyphers) and what you expect the return results to be for that data?

Comment: I was working on something just like this, I believe its the correct direction I need to go.  Just getting a Neo4j::Server::CypherResponse::ResponseError: Unknown expression type during transformation (class org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_3.ast.NestedPlanExpression)

Possibly due to the Filters in the return?

Comment: @ndyr What version of Neo4j are you running? Test `RETURN *` to see if FILTER in return is the problem. If it is, try changing that RETURN to WITH and then return after that. (I tested it on 3.1 and didn't see this problem)

Comment: I went the WITH then RETURN route,  getting everything I need now!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This query might do what you want:

```
MATCH (z:Z)<-[:rel2]-(b:B { uuid: {id} })
WITH COLLECT(z) as all_zs
UNWIND all_zs AS z
MATCH (a)-[:rel1]->(z)
WITH all_zs, COLLECT(DISTINCT z) AS matched_zs
RETURN matched_zs, apoc.coll.subtract(all_zs, matched_zs) AS missing_zs;
```

It first stores in the `all_zs` variable all the `Z` nodes that have a `rel2` relationship from `b`. This collection's contents remain unaffected even if the second `MATCH` clause matches a subset of those `Z` nodes.

It then stores in `matched_zs` the distinct `all_zs` nodes that have a `rel1` relationship from any `A` node.

Finally, it returns:

- the `matched_zs` collection, and
- the unique nodes from `all_zs` that are not also in `matched_zs`, as `missing_zs`.

The query uses the convenient APOC function [apoc.coll.subtract](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) to generate the latter return value.